# Solr can not process rich documents but already fetched

Tags: search, solr, data-import

Recently, I am trying to adopt Solr to search rich document files(e.g. .pdf, .doc, xls ...etc)

When I try to import all the files from the disk using Solr admin UI (localhost:18983/solr/#/local.info/dataimport//dataimport), the message always shows "Index Completed" but no document added/updated.

[Data Import Messages Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeSnf.png)

I have also checked the official online manual to index a directory of rich files(lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html#indexing-a-directory-of-rich-files).

The error messages showed

```
     SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: localhost:8983/solr/local.info/update/extract?resource.name=%2Fvar%2Fsolr%2Fdata%2Flocal.info%2Frich_documents%2FNEWS.PDF&literal.id=%2Fvar%2Fsolr%2Fdata%2Flocal.info%2Frich_documents%2FNEWS.PDF

  SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: 
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <response>
     <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">400</int>
         <int name="QTime">71</int>
     </lst>
     <lst name="error">
        <str name="msg">
           Invalid UUID String: '/var/solr/data/local.info/rich_documents/NEWS.PDF'</str>
        <int name="code">400</int></lst>
      </response>
```

Here are my configs

data-config.xml, solrconfig.xml, schema.xml
[Configs Link](http://pastie.org/private/vvhfjslqqn11n3hcyo6hq)

Anyone has idea to fix this problem?

Thanks